# What overwrites the <executble-name>.exe.config file with the original App.config at the end of debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, configuration, app-config, configuration-files

In Visual Studio 2010 what overwrites the <executable-name>.exe.config and replaces it with the App.config version of the file when debugging ends?

Is it Visual Studio doing that?  Is there any way of toggling this functionality?

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
           // ... Modify configuration.AppSettings.Settings by 
           // running Add/Remove on a couple of keys.

           // Write out the <executable-name>.exe.config file...
           configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

           // Break here and notice that the file has been written to.
           ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings"); 
 }
```

**Example** - Writing out settings on exit

Notice where I break at the end of the `_FormClosing` handler method.

Answer (score 2):

The Save() method only saves settings whose Scope is user, not Application.  Those setting values get written to a user.config file that's stored in a subdirectory of c:\users\name\appdata.  It is hard to find, the subdirectory name is a hash based on the application name and version.

Which is the way it has to work, a program doesn't normally have write access to the app.exe.config file after it got deployed.  UAC prevents a program from writing to files in c:\program files.

In other words, your app.exe.config is not supposed to change.  Look at it with notepad to verify that.

Comment: For what I'm going with it, it will probably be okay, but none the less, good to know.

Comment: What should I use instead? (to write my configuration back out)

Comment: Why do you want to fix anything?  Sounds to me that it works like it should.  Just make sure you made settings you want to change have Scope = user so they'll be saved.  Don't try to write app.exe.config, that won't work in practice.

Comment: Oh okay, so just change the location of the file then so it points to %USERPROFILE%\appdata\some-nasty-hash\user.config ?

Comment: You cannot change the location yourself.  You should never be interested in the actual file.  If that is important to you then you should not use application settings.